# NJasmine in Production

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, nunit, bdd

Is anyone using NJasmine in a production project right now?  I'm loving the idea of a simpler TDD solution sort of like "developer level TDD".  NJasmine looks awesome but also very young.  Is anyone using it in Prod?

Comment: I looked into NJasmine, and I also thought it looked great, having just jumped into Jasmine for our JavaScript tests.  We decided against using it for now, though, because it requires its own test runners (as opposed to piggybacking on NUnit or another widely used framework, as several other bdd tools do), and we just didn't want to deal with that added complexity right now.

Comment: That's good to know.  I don't want to take a dependency on another test runner either.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually not too bad since it depends on modified famous NUnit Runner regarding the benefit it brings to the table. my test code is cleaner. (note: a unit of code to be tested is a scenario)